# Call a hook function to show a hook instance passed in parameter

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a Container hook with ref containerRef.

I want to be able to call a show method with a hook instance passed in parameter so that the hook instance is rendered in MyContainer like so :

```
<div>
    <MyContainer ref={containerRef}/>
    <button onClick={()=>containerRef.current.show(myHookInstance)}>click</button>
</div>
```

And here is my full code:

```
import React, {forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState} from 'react';

const MyContainer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState('');

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        show: (content = null) => {
            setShowContent(content)
        },
    }));
    return (
        <div>
            this is the content:
            {showContent}
        </div>
    )
})

const MyForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text"
                   id="name"
                   value={name}
                   onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const containerRef = React.createRef()
    const myForm = MyForm()
    return (
        <div>
            <MyContainer ref={containerRef}/>
            <button onClick={()=>containerRef.current.show(myForm)}>click</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that when I type in the form input it's not displayed.

From what I understood, it's a very bad practice to store a hook instance in the state.

Do you have any advice ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: This is very convoluted way to show/hide content. Why don't you have a boolean flag in `MyContainer` and just show/hide children? To fix your approach `const myForm = <MyForm />`

Comment: Thank you Yuri.
const myForm = <MyForm /> fixed the problem :)
Actualy I simplified the problem at the maximum, but in my case I have to provide the instance as parameter onclick and could not put it in the children.

Is that a bad practice to store it in the state ? :
setShowContent(content)

Answer (score 0):

MyForm isn't a hook but a functional component and yes you shouldn't store hook in state instead you can conditionally render it

```
import React, {forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState} from 'react';

const MyContainer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState('');

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        show: () => {
            setShowContent(true);
        },
    }));
    return (
        <div>
            this is the content:
            {showContent && <MyForm />}
        </div>
    )
})

const MyForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text"
                   id="name"
                   value={name}
                   onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const containerRef = React.createRef()
    return (
        <div>
            <MyContainer ref={containerRef}/>
            <button onClick={()=>containerRef.current.show()}>click</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shubham, but actualy I need the show method to receive any content as parameter like in the following code:

```
import React, {forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState} from 'react';

const MyContainer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState('');

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        show: (content = null) => {
            setShowContent(content)
        },
    }));
    return (
        <div>
            this is the content:
            {showContent}
        </div>
    )
})

const MyForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text"
                   id="name"
                   value={name}
                   onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
    )
}

const AnotherContent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Another content !
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    const containerRef = React.createRef()
    const myForm = <MyForm />
    const anotherContent = <AnotherContent />
    return (
        <div>
            <MyContainer ref={containerRef}/>
            <button onClick={()=>containerRef.current.show(myForm)}>show MyForm</button>
            <button onClick={()=>containerRef.current.show(anotherContent)}>show AnotherContent</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How would you improve it ?